# combine 'where' with 'or' in mongoDB using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I use morphia to map Java to mongoDB.
I have this Document-Structure

```
{
  "endTime" : 12345678
  "array" : [
             {
               "time" : 12345678
               ...
             },
             {
               "time" : 12345679
               ...
             }             
          ]
}
```

I want to delete a document if an array ("arrayField") doesn't exists or the field "time" of the last item of this array.

I can do something like this in mongodb-shell:

```
db.Test.remove({ $or: [{ "id.endTime" :{$lt: 1401273405555 }},
                       { arrayField: { $exists: false}},
                       {"$where" : "this.arrayField.length &&
                           this.arrayField[this.arrayField.length-1].time < 123457"}
                      ]})
```

but how can do that with morphia?
I've tried this

```
Query<Test> q = db.createQuery(Test.class);
q.or(
    q.criteria("endTime").lessThan(now), 
    q.criteria("arrayField").doesNotExist()),
    q.where("this.arrayField.length && this.arrayField[this.arrayField.length-1].time < " + now)
);
```

but the compiler says: "The method or(Criteria...) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (capture#5-of ? extends CriteriaContainerImpl, capture#6-of ? extends CriteriaContainerImpl, Query)"

Comment: Even though I don't know the answer a little bit of advice, that query, if your table grows, will become unmanageable. This seems like time based analytical events so I thought I would do say that

Comment: Why is `$exits` not enough? I'm not seeing the rationale here for JavaScript evaluation. Never a good idea.

Comment: but how can i write this with ´$exits´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Query<Test> q = db.createQuery(Test.class);
q.or(
  q.criteria("endTime").lessThan(now), 
  q.criteria("arrayField").doesNotExist()),
  new WhereCriteria("'this.arrayField.length && this.arrayField[this.arrayField.length-1].time < " + now +"'")
);
```